# Connect to a server without opening Finder windows for each mounted volume

Tags: macos, finder

When I connect to my server and mount all its volumes, new Finder windows open for each volume. This is new behavior in Lion (10.7), it just connected silently in SnowLeopard (10.6).

How can I connect in Lion without new Finder windows opening up?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to test it, but would any of these change the behavior?

```
defaults write com.apple.finder OpenWindowForNewRemovableDisk -bool false
defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-ro-root -bool false
defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-rw-root -bool false
osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
```